# How to remove authorize functionality in case of login endpoint in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, jwt, unauthorized, authorize

I have created two endpoints one for login and other for logout and used JWT token to authorize the endpoint.
So when I authorize the whole class using [Authorize] it authorizes both the login and logout endpoint. Not I want to remove authorize functionality from Login endpoint only.
So how it can be done?

I tried the same using [AllowAnonymous] but it is not working in my case.
**Note:** I cannot remove authorize from the whole controller and apply it only to the logout endpoint because I have some other cases too and it can not be done.

This is what I tried to do:

```
[Authorize(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class UserController : Controller {

   [AllowAnonymous]
   public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string userDetails) {
      // This action can be accessed by unauthorized users
   }

   public async Task<IActionResult> Logout(int Id) {
      // This action can NOT be accessed by unauthorized users
   }
}
```

Comment: You can maybe create AuthController for login and logout endpoints without attribute.Otherwise you can put the attribute for all methods but the login and remove it from the top of the class.

Comment: `AllowAnonymous` should do the trick. Try rebuilding/restarting the app. Also check from which namespace the attribute comes from. Also what ASP version are you using?

Comment: Refer to this [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple?view=aspnetcore-7.0), It show the same code as you want, I don't find any unusual in your code.